# How to eager load an list or array of objects in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eager-loading

I have the following next/image in one of my pages, with priority set to true to eager load the asset from the state

```
const [imageToUse, setImageToUse] = useState(initialImage);

<Image src={imageToUse} alt='scrolls' priority={true} ... />
```

I have set state in such a way that it would listen on scroll event and have it calls the state `imageToUse` from a new image as the user scrolls:

```
 const cycleImages = {
    1: "/header/_0011.webp",
    2: "/header/_0012.webp",
    3: "/header/_0013.webp",
    ....
    37: "/header/_0047.webp",
}

 useEffect(() => {
    // scrolled at every 30 pixels
    const y = clientWindowHeight / 30;
    // Scroll event distance + cycle through a list of objects
    let label = Math.min(Math.floor(y) + 1, 37)
    // Set imageToUse
    let image = cycleImages[label]
    setImageToUse(image)
}
```

The above logic works, but the only problem I have is that `<Image />` only eager loads the initial image or the image that is about to be scrolled through - whereas I want it to eager load all 37 images and to avoid fetching ONLY when it is scrolls to and create stutter (i.e. bad user experience).

So how do I eager load all 37 images in NextJS?

Answer (score 0):

To load eager Next.js images, you can use the priority attribute on the Image component. Here's an example:

import Image from 'next/image';

```
  <Image
    src="/my-image.jpg"
    alt="My image"
    width={500}
    height={500}
    priority
  />
```